# Ajax form reloads the page instead of calling the ajax code

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, submit

I'm trying to run some php code without refreshing the page by using a form and Ajax. But it just refreshes the page without even trying to run the ajax function. There should be something simple missing, because this exact same code worked for other forms, even on the same page (with different names)

HTML form:

```
<form class='ajax_file_remove_form'>
    <input type='hidden' name='ind' value='0'>
    <input type='hidden' name='type' value='image'>
    <input type='submit' class='ajax_file_remove_form_submit' name='remove_file' 
    value='Remove' style='height: 100%'>
</form>
```

Javascript file, inside `$(document).ready(function () {});`:

```
$('.ajax_file_remove_form').off().on("submit", function (e) {
    console.log("ATTEMPT AJAX FILE REMOVE");
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var form = $(this);
    var data = new FormData(form[0]);

    $.ajax({
            url: "../ajax_file_remove.php",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: data,
            success: function (data) { 
                console.log("AJAX FILE REMOVED"); 
                console.log(data); file_preview(data); 
            }
        });
})
```

The console just says 
Navigated to mySite.com/?ind=0&type=image&remove_file=Remove

instead of ATTEMPT AJAX FILE REMOVE

I tried to make the form method='post', but it still only refreshed the page, and the ajax function already says "POST"

Also tried $('.ajax_file_remove_form_submit').off().on("click", function (e)
or to remove the .off() or other things that i'm not sure are needed here.

Thanks :)

Comment: The simple thing to do is to not have <input type="submit" , but rather <input type="button"

Comment: hmm, but then it doesn't trigger the submit event, so i tried to use the click event on the button and didn't seem to work either

Comment: You are putting a form listener for post and calling ajax.  Have a clear separation from post and ajax.  You want ajax, so assign a button click to the ajax <input type="button" id="aBtn..     $(function () {        $("#btnClick").click(function () { $.ajax..  }                                     })

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation - http://api.jquery.com/off/

```
.off() Remove an event handler.
```

`.off()` function is misplaced in

```
$('.ajax_file_remove_form').off().on("submit", function (e) {
```

i think you should put or use the .off function if this ajax is successful.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "../ajax_file_remove.php",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: data,
        success: function (data) { 
            console.log("AJAX FILE REMOVED"); 
            console.log(data); file_preview(data); 
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried to remove the off function but it didn't change anything. Earlier i had a problem where it was running the ajax function 3 times from 1 button click. So I found the solution in another question to put .off() in there and it worked.

Comment: url: "../ajax_file_remove.php" ---- is this the correct path of the php file? can you try adding error handling for the ajax and see if it fails? ( error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
      
    }) )

Comment: Yes, but I don't think it gets that far in the code because console.log("ATTEMPT AJAX FILE REMOVE"); doesn't show up in the console